# Updating a WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid

I have an application that displays, using a data grid, a DbSet (Entity Framework 5).
When I change some of the entities using code, the end-user has to perform some action (like reordering the columns or editing a cell) to update the datagrid.

XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="componentViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Models:Component}, CreateList=True}"/>

<TabItem Header="Components">
    <DataGrid x:Name="componentDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource componentViewSource}}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="componentTypeColumn" Binding="{Binding ComponentType}" Header="Component Type" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="descriptionColumn1" Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="catalogNumberColumn1" Binding="{Binding CatalogNumber}" Header="Catalog Number" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="commentColumn1" Binding="{Binding Comment}" Header="Comment" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="digiKeyColumn" Binding="{Binding DigiKey}" Header="Digi Key" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="farnellColumn" Binding="{Binding Farnell}" Header="Farnell" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="inStockColumn" Binding="{Binding InStock}" Header="In Stock" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="minimumStockColumn" Binding="{Binding MinimumStock}" Header="Minimum Stock" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="manufacturerColumn" Binding="{Binding Manufacturer}" Header="Manufacturer" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="manufacturerPNColumn" Binding="{Binding ManufacturerPN}" Header="Manufacturer PN" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="mouserColumn" Binding="{Binding Mouser}" Header="Mouser" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="packageColumn" Binding="{Binding Package}" Header="Package" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="priceColumn" Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="subTotalColumn" Binding="{Binding SubTotal}" Header="Sub Total" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="valueColumn" Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</TabItem>
```

C#:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // That's a private field.
    componentViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("componentViewSource");

    // That's the database context.
    db = new PotatoContext();
    db.Components.Load();
    componentViewSource.Source = db.Components.Local;
}
private void Manufacture_Product_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var product = productDataGrid.SelectedItem as Product;
    if(product == null)
        return;
    ManufactureProduct d = new ManufactureProduct(product, db);
    d.Owner = this;
    d.ShowDialog();
    if (d.DialogResult ?? false)
    {
        foreach (var comp in product.Components)
        {
            comp.Component.InStock -= comp.Quantity * d.NumberOfUnits;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        var fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}.txt", ReportGenerator.ProductReportsFolder,
            System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, product.Name, DateTime.Now.ToString("d.MMM.yyyy HH.mm"));
        using(var file = File.Create(fileName)) 
        {
            ReportGenerator.GenerateProductionReport(file, product, d.NumberOfUnits);
        }
    }

}
```

In the foreach loop inside the second event handler, I change a property of a component (which is already part of the PotatoContext), and then I save the context.

When I look at the data grid, the old values are still kept, and I need to enter edit mode on some cell to update that specific cell, or click a column header to update all cells.

This bothers me because an unaware user might not know to do so.
How can I refresh the components from code? ( I've tried Grid.Items.Refresh(); )

Comment: Do your objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx. Note that when you bind to a DbSet<T>.Local property you are only notified if the collection changes not if a property of an object inside it changes, hence my question.

Comment: No, they do not. I will implement :). Thank you very much.